# How to export and import apk in android studio software development?

Tags: android-studio, apk

I want to know the steps to import and export the app apk to perform some changes in the existing app and vice versa.. Also where to find the apk in android studio environment..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In **Android Studio**. Go to **Build** in the toolbar. Click on **Generate Signed APK** and then go through the steps such as creating a keystone and the like. It's very easy and the IDE does most of the work. When creating the keystone choose a certain scale that will ensure the keystore is in place and secure for the next several decades. You will be able to use it for that many years.

In **Eclipse**. Single click on the project you would like to generate the signed APL for and then from the **File** tab in the toolbar, click on **Export**. The remaining steps are mostly the same as above.

Type in your information, such as location, country code, and you will finally be presented with a signed APK. Good-Luck and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: But the studio is not showing any apk file in generate option.

Comment: There will be one after you generate it. For now you have to use your main app folder. If my answer helped, just click the check mark. Goodbye. :)